# Mysqldump with custom option

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I normally use phpmyadmin to do the export of a database mainly because it's easiest to select custom options.

But now i want to know how to do that with the command line. Now i have:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --databases <ddbb_name> --add-drop-database --disable-keys --add-drop-table --quick | gzip > dump.sql.gz
```

what i want is (got from phpmyadmin):

- compression gzip
- "Disable foreign key check"
- Add "create database / use" statement
- Add "drop table /view /prodecure /function / event / trigger" statement

do you think it's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where to look for all the options and their explanation -> [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#option_mysqlpump_skip-definer)

And i think my code is correct